# Run dataset on every auto refresh

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am using Report Builder 3.0 and have a dataset that when it runs it increments a value in a table, this determines which subreport to display thanks to expressions.

My problem is that when I set it to auto refresh the dataset query doesn't run again after the first time the report is ran. It will run and display the other subreport if I manually hit refresh but not automatically.

How can I make it so the query in the data set runs every time unattended.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring back to your earlier question here.. [Can you rotate through visible sub reports in report builder 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666925/can-you-rotate-through-visible-sub-reports-in-report-builder-3)

It looks like using the parameter won't work as it does not get refreshed. However you can use the value the `dsLoop` returns directly. To make the change, simply swap out

`Parameters!pLoopPos.Value` with `=First(Fields!LPos.Value, "dsLoop")`

**Note**: I modified the `dsLoop` query slightly to give the final result a name (`LPos`).

You should now be able to delete the parameter as its no longer used.

**UPDATE:**
The query for dsLoop should be this (assuming you have a table called myReportLoopTable with columns `LoopPosition`, `LoopMax` and `Reportname`)

```
DECLARE @LoopPosition int
SELECT @LoopPosition =  CASE LoopPosition WHEN LoopMax THEN 1 ELSE LoopPosition + 1 END
    select * FROM ReportLoopTable 
    WHERE ReportName = 'myReportName'

    UPDATE ReportLoopTable Set LoopPosition = @LoopPosition WHERE ReportName = 'myReportName'

SELECT @LoopPosition as lPos
```

The script to create the table would be

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReportLoopTable](
    [LoopPosition] [int] NULL,
    [LoopMax] [int] NULL,
    [ReportName] [varchar](10) NULL
)
```

In the table it should have something like

```
LoopPosition    LoopMax ReportName
1               3       'myReportname'
```

Below is a link to a sample report RDL I created to test this. You'll need to add it to your project and configure the data source to point to your database then it should work . It switches visibility of 3 text boxes but the principle is the same for sub reports.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvWOxxoIjY1UlwWbHGG8l_rzDba2

Comment: Hi Alan, appreciate the answer unfortunately the loop value doesn't change at all with each auto refresh, as I ran a query in sql management studio after each refresh and the value never changed.

The parameter might not update as well but it seems the dataset doesn't run again after the initial starting the report.

Comment: The code is wrong then. I tested this and it worked perfectly. Post your dataset code and I'll take a look.

Comment: DECLARE atLoopPosition int
SELECT atLoopPosition =  CASE LoopPosition WHEN LoopMax THEN 1 ELSE LoopPosition + 1 END
    FROM myReportLoopTable 
    WHERE ReportName = 'MyMainReport'

 SELECT atLoopPosition AS Loop

 if (SELECT LoopPosition FROM myReportLoopTable WHERE ReportName = 'MyMainReport') = (SELECT LoopMax FROM myReportLoopTable WHERE ReportName = 'MyMainReport')
 UPDATE myReportLoopTable Set LoopPosition = 1 WHERE ReportName = 'MyMainReport'
 ELSE
    UPDATE myReportLoopTable Set LoopPosition = LoopPosition + 1 WHERE ReportName = 'MyMainReport'

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the correct query. I'm not sure where you got that from, it's not what I originally posted.

Comment: thanks again but still no luck. Using your code keeps doing the same thing. I downloaded your report and get an error when trying to open so maybe we have different versions of report builder that could be causing the differences?
Error for reference:
"Failed to open report 'AutoRefreshVisibilitySwitch.rdl'
The report definition has an invalid target namespace which cannot be upgraded."

Comment: I'm using VS2015 not report builder but that won;t be the problem. Are you testing in ReportBuilder or deployed? I can download ReportBuilder 3 and reproduce it there if you want.

Comment: I have been using ReportBuilder 3.0 to create and test this

Comment: OK, I'll download RB3 and build the same thing there. It won;t be until this evening (UK time) though.

Comment: I've uploaded a version done in ReportBuilder 3.0 hopefully you can use this. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvWOxxoIjY1UlwatsmA7u3vJjQBZ

Comment: Thanks for the help, sadly its the same issue as I've been having with mine. I have moved on to achieve what I want with VS however I will leave the question up in case someone can supply an answer.

Comment: I can't understand it. It worked perfectly for me both in VS and Report Builder. Did you run my sample as - is or make changes to it?

Comment: I ran yours as is, all I had to do was change to my data source and table names. The autorefresh still does not run the dataset again.

Comment: I played around with it some more there and came across an interesting thing. It fails and causes this problem when I run against a shared data source, however if I make the same connection embedded in my report it works!

Comment: Sounds like the data source is caching, not sure if this is something you can even configure, but glad you got it working in the end.

Comment: Must be that. Sorry for the hassle and thanks for the help!