# SSRS Autorefresh and looping - is it possible?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, page-numbering

I have an SSRS report which currently is 7 pages long. This report is on display in the office and  auto-refreshes every 20 secs to show the latest results from a dataset. I would like the report to go up a page on auto-refresh and then when it gets to last page loop back to page one and continue on and on as so.
I have looked everywhere on here and other forums and cannot find anything tangible or adaptable. Before I tell the powers that be in the office 'NO!' - is there a simple way to achieve this?

I am using Visual Studio 2019

Many thanks for any help in advance

Tried to write an expression for Autorefresh using parameters

Comment: You can do this. Take a look at this answer of mine from 5 years ago... It's based on you creating a subreport for each page and then switching visibility based on a value held in a table with gets incremented each refresh. It also includes a sample RDL (if the link still works). If its not helpful, comment here and I'll post a new more relevant answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747329/run-dataset-on-every-auto-refresh/49755495#49755495