# Slideshow for multiple SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, slideshow, ssrs-2012

I have 8 subreports in one report and want to create the slideshow using the expression in 'visibility' property. I want refresh time of report 15 seconds and sequence should be same as in the report.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS doesn't have built-in functionality for this. One option would be to set up a page that has the reports embedded in it. You could adjust the timing and visibility using JavaScript.

There's going to be a loading delay each time you switch reports. Make sure you also consider enabling caching on the reports to optimize the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered something very similar recently here [Can you rotate through visible sub reports in report builder 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666925/can-you-rotate-through-visible-sub-reports-in-report-builder-3/49689700#49689700)

The sample project I supplied is no longer part of the question so I'll link it again here. The Sample report is for use in ReportBuilder 3.0 for sake of compatibility with the last OP's setup.

The sample loops thru 3 text boxes but the principle is the same as I described in the answer.

Hers the link to the sample..

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvWOxxoIjY1UlwatsmA7u3vJjQBZ